# javascript regex when diffrent length of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of digits that's supposed to have 9 characters and I have a regex that replaces the string with the same string and some spaces; something like this:

```
TheString = '123456789';
TheSpacedString = TheString.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5');
TheSpacedString format is now '1 23 45 67 89'
```

The problem is that when the length of the string is not 9, the formatting doesn't work: for instance, if we have this:

```
TheString = '12345';
TheSpacedString = TheString.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5');
format should be '1 23 45'
```

But instead, the string is just `'12345'`. What's the problem with my regex? The jsFiddle is **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/yWSR2/1/)**

Comment: Your regex doesn't match - so of course it does nothing.

Comment: You should add validation before you perform your replacement - if you're expecting 9 digits but don't get 9, shouldn't that be an error first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the last two groups (or however many you think should be optional) optional with `?`

http://jsfiddle.net/yWSR2/3/

```
TheSpacedString = TheString.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})?(\d{2})?/, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5');
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, fixed my day! Upvoted!! Actually, I added a question mark after each block and it works perfectly!!

Comment: Though it will add some trailing spaces like: `"1 23 45  "` better to call `.trim()` after this.